# How to set nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: linux, nginx, reverse-proxy

On `landing.example.com:10000` have I a webserver that works fine, which is a Docker container that exposes port `10000`. Its IP is `172.17.0.2`.

What I would like is having a nginx reverse proxy on port `80`, and send the visitor to different Docker containers depending on the URL they visit.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name landing.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:10000/;
    }

    access_log /landing-access.log;
    error_log  /landing-error.log info;
}
```

When I do this, I get `502 Bad Gateway` and the log says

```
2016/04/14 16:58:16 [error] 413#413: *84 connect()
failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: landing.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:10000/", host: "landing.example.com"
```

Comment: I need help, where do you find the logs?

Comment: I don't know if someone can still change this, the question is how to debug a 502 bad gateway, then proceeds with their config that they have an issue. The answer is how to fix it, not how to debug, every google search on how to debug gives this topic when it just isn't telling us anything about debugging it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The server doesn't answer because it is not defined as an upstream.

try this:

```
upstream my_server {
   server 172.17.0.2:10000;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name landing.example.com;
   location / {
      proxy_pass                  http://my_server;
      proxy_set_header            Host $host;
      proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_http_version          1.1;
      proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Proto http;
      proxy_redirect              http:// $scheme://;
   }
}
```

Here you define the upstream server (your server by IP or hostname)
and make sure to forward the headers too so the server answering knowns who to answer to.

Comment: Is it possible to perform POST requests without data lost?